# Python double iteration

Tags: python

What is the pythonic way of iterating simultaneously over two lists?

Suppose I want to compare two files line by line (compare each `i`th line in one file with the `i`th line of the other file), I would want to do something like this:

```
file1 = csv.reader(open(filename1),...)
file2 = csv.reader(open(filename2),...)

for line1 in file1 and line2 in file2: #pseudo-code!
    if line1 != line2:
        print "files are not identical"
        break
```

What is the pythonic way of achieving this?

---

**Edit:** I am not using a file handler but rather a CSV reader (`csv.reader(open(file),...)`), and `zip()` doesn't seem to work with it...

---

**Final edit:** like @Alex M. suggested, `zip()` loads the files to memory on first iteration, so on big files this is an issue. On Python 2, using `itertools` solves the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I iterate through two lists in parallel in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-can-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel-in-python)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Python 2, you should import [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#module-itertools) and use its [izip](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.izip):

```
with open(file1) as f1:
  with open(file2) as f2:
    for line1, line2 in itertools.izip(f1, f2):
      if line1 != line2:
        print 'files are different'
        break
```

with the built-in `zip`, both files will be entirely read into memory at once at the start of the loop, which may not be what you want.  In Python 3, the built-in `zip` works like `itertools.izip` does in Python 2 -- incrementally.

Comment: This does the job! Indeed the problem was that the files were pretty large and `zip()` was loading them all to memory...

Comment: Ah, maybe that's why I see no difference. I'm using Python 3.1.

Comment: @KennyTM, yep, no "maybe": in Python 3 many things that used to rely on all-in-memory lists in Python 2, have become incremental and iterative. So it's important to always clarify whether questions and answers relate to Python 2 or Python 3 -- in Python 2 the (better;-) incremental and iterative approach is, so to speak, "opt-in" (you need to get it explicitly), in Python 3 it's intrinsic (you need to explicitly call `list` in the relative rare cases where you actually **do** want a list, all in memory at once;-).

Comment: Just a small note: you can, if you want, `open` both files within the same `with` statement: `with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2`:

Answer (score 12):

I vote for using `zip`. The [manual](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) suggests "To loop over two or more sequences at the same time, the entries can be paired with the zip() function"

For example,

```
list_one = ['nachos', 'sandwich', 'name']
list_two = ['nachos', 'sandwich', 'the game']
for one, two in zip(list_one, list_two):
   if one != two:
      print "Difference found"
```

Answer (score 4):

In lockstep (for Python ≥3):

```
for line1, line2 in zip(file1, file2):
   # etc.
```

As a "2D array":

```
for line1 in file1:
   for line2 in file2:
     # etc.
   # you may need to rewind file2 to the beginning.
```

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for the lockstep method. Any idea why this method doesn't work for a `csv.reader()`?

Comment: maybe you should clarify that for the "2D array" one might need to reinitialise the inner iterator...

Comment: @Yuval, please edit your answer to show exactly how you're trying to use zip with a (one?!) csv.reader -- this comment is totally mysterious.