# How to compare index of each value in two lists python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, nested-lists

I have a list of 6 files and a list of 6 mac addresses. Each mac address corresponds to the file in the same list slot. For instance, `mac_list[1]` corresponds to `file_list[1]`, `mac_list[2]` corresponds to `file_list[2]`, etc. Each file already contains a mac address which is incorrect, so I need to overwrite the incorrect one with the new one (from `mac_list`) which exists at the corresponding index in `mac_list`. The actual replacement of each mac address I know how to do with sed. What I don't know how to do is only access the values which exist at the same index in both lists. My initial thought was to use a nested for loop for both lists and compare their indexes:

```
for addr in mac_list:
  for file in file_list:
     if addr.index == file.index:
        #overwrite mac address
```

But is there a more efficient approach to this?

Comment: `zip` is what you are looking for, i think

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python double iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393444/python-double-iteration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` is the easiest approach:

```
mac_list = [1, 2, 3] # for example
file_list = [4, 5, 6]

for item1, item2 in zip(mac_list, file_list):
    print(item1, item2)
    #overwrite mac address

# prints:
# 1 4
# 2 5
# 3 6
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I was hoping for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `zip`:

```
for addr, file in zip(mac_list, file_list):
    # to-do
```

You can alternatively but not-preferably use a common index counter:

```
# if the lists have the same length
for i in range(len(mac_list)):
    addr, file = mac_list[i], file_list[i]
    # to-do

# if you're not sure that they have the same length
l = min(len(mac_list), len(file_list))
for i in range(l): # if the lists have the same length
    addr, file = mac_list[i], file_list[i]
    # to-do
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> file_list=[1,2,3]
>>> mac_list=['x','y','z']
>>> zip(file_list,mac_list)
<zip object at 0x10a2c1388>
>>> list(zip(file_list,mac_list))
[(1, 'x'), (2, 'y'), (3, 'z')]
>>> dict(zip(file_list,mac_list))
{1: 'x', 2: 'y', 3: 'z'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you generate the 2 lists, but it will be much more efficient to generate a dict, then you can do O(1) lookup with no need to iterate.

If you insist on 2 lists, then:

```
for index, file in enumerate(file_list):
    relevant_mac = mac_list[index]
```

Or `zip` as been suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

In general you usually don't need to use `index` of arrays in Python, unless you really are implementing complex algorithms.
but for completeness this is how you would solve it using indexes:

```
for idx, addr in enumerate(mac_list):
   file = file_list[idx]
   #...
```

as the other answers mention,  `zip` is the pythonic way to do it.